# Destroy or recalculate CSS nth-child selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

**Context**:

I have a list. Using jQuery, I'm dynamically...

1. ...hiding/showing certain list-items.
2. ...calculating the third and fourth list-items to apply specific classes.

**Problem**:

A CSS style (from a stylesheet), using an nth-child selector, is being applied to every third list item. The problem is that when I dynamically hide/show list items, the CSS nth-child selector doesn't seem to be recalculating.

Since jQuery is already calculating the third list item, I don't need to recalculate the CSS nth-child selector unless there is no means of cancelling it out or destroying it.

**Code**:

**The mark-up:**

```
<ul class="teamlist">
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
</ul>
```

**The jQuery:**

```
$('.teamlist li:visible').each(function (i) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) $(this).addClass('teamlist_fourth_item');
});
$('.teamlist li:visible').each(function (i) {
   if ((i+1) % 3 == 0) $(this).addClass('teamlist_third_item');
});
```

**The unwanted CSS:**

```
.teamlist li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

**Question**:

How do I destroy or force the recalculation of CSS nth-child selector?

Comment: I would use javascript to apply the nth-child class as a function, this way it will work down to IE8 and then everytime you run your code to add or remove a list item it would recalculate

Comment: `nth-child` doesn't change for hidden elements, so unless you're adding or removing DOM nodes, CSS won't suddenly change which elements are matched.

Comment: The easy answer is destroy the CSS ... so just remove it form the file  what is the real problem ?

Comment: @Danko - Removing the code (rather than destroying or overriding it) requires me to edit a parent WordPress theme (which won't survive upgrades). I was hoping to figure out a swift way of countering the undesired style without deleting it.

Comment: Thanks more clear to me i guess you have a default margin-right for all the li elements and are you able to write a new css rule?

Comment: So you just want to kill the zero margin from the stylesheet? Do you know the margin you'd like to be set if the CSS wasn't there? Because you could just set inline CSS to override the 0 to whatever value that is on page load. e.g. `$(".teamlist li").css('margin-right', '15px');`. The inline CSS will always trump the stylesheet, and all your margins will be 15px.

Comment: @Danko - Yes. The default is `margin-right:2%`. Every third list-item is set `margin-right:0px;`. Setting every third list-items to `margin-right:0px;` using cascading does the trick since jQuery handles the desired styling of every third list item. The problem occurs when I dynamically hide/show list items. The nth-child CSS selector doesn't recalculate and I end up with a list item with `margin-right:0px;` in the wrong place.

Comment: @MattGibson - See my prior comment to Danko. The problem is more to do with the third list item not being dynamically calculated rather than the ability to cascade the undesired style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the comments i think what you need is to override that class to make it just equal with the properties for all `li` elements, you can make your own class that match those elements with a better level of specificity, for example with the `id` or `class` of the parent ul:

```
#parent .teamlist li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right:2%;
}
```

Or with an id on your `ul`

```
<ul class="teamlist" id="lista">

#lista.teamlist li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right:2%;
}
```

<sub>Also try to be sure your CSS is loaded after the other one</sub>

Other way you can work with Jquery too and modify this with the same CSS selector:

```
$('.teamlist li:nth-child(3n+3)').css('margin-right','2%');
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! I equalised nth-child style and allowed jQuery to handle the calculation of the third list item. When I tried this earlier, my selector didn't have the greater specificity and was therefore being overridden.