# Hiding div boxes and removing space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navigation by which you can filter div boxes:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="apples">Appels</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="bananas">Bananas</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="pineapples">Pineapples</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="fruits bananas apples pineapples"></div>  
<div class="fruits bananas"></div>
<div class="fruits pineapples apples"></div>
```

My goal: When you click on a fruit those div boxes which do not contain the fruit in their classes hide - but: they shall not just hide, but also provide their space for the upcoming div boxes. Here comes my jQuery function that I have come up with so far:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('a[data-target]').click(function() {
              jQuery('.fruits').show().not('.' + this.dataset.target).hide();
        });

    });
```

My two problems that I am still having:

- In the frontend I have five rows, with each row containing three div.fruits boxes. Each div has a width of 33%. The function above achieves that the unwanted div boxes hide, but if for example the only box that is being hidden is the last box in row #1, then the first box of row #2 does not automatically move up to the position where the hidden box was - on the contrary, there is white space that the hidden boxes leave.
- My second requirement: Let's say you have clicked on the apple link in order to filter all "apples" boxes - if after that you decide to click the "pineapples" link than of course all the div boxes that might have been hidden after the apple-click need to be considered for the new filter query.

I'll be grateful for your code suggestions!

Here comes my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Karicula/LXmjp/#&togetherjs=UImBqeN3DU
Click on "Apples" to see my problem...

Comment: share you CSS also... OR better you create a fiddle and share the link!

Comment: Are we supposed to visualize all this in mind and come up with a solution?

Comment: @tilwinjoy i am working on the fiddle. I am a fiddle newbie: how do I save my fiddle? the link I generated does not work and my code is not shown when I open it in a different browser for example

Comment: @sunny Okay, here comes my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Karicula/LXmjp/#&togetherjs=UImBqeN3DU

Comment: @tilwinJoy In the fiddle, click on "Apples" to see my problem

Comment: The fiddle you shared is empty. simply put the HTML, JS, and CSS in the respective windows and click save, and share the new url..

Comment: @tilwinjoy there is no save button

Comment: That is because you already saved it. i'm talking about a new fiddle. once you save it, it'll change to `update`. You can use this to save the fiddle as a new version after making major changes..

Comment: I have to go now but i assume you have to consider that the nth-child selector has to be recalculated - [see comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336437/destroy-or-recalculate-css-nth-child-selector). I will continue to work on [my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/XYv5y/3/) later.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relies on this style

```
.fruits:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

remove this and change your `.fruits` class `margin-right` property to `0.3%`